# Django compare two queryset and append custom object

Tags: python, django, append, compare, django-queryset

I have two models

```
class Position(models.Model):
    ...   
    job_seekers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class Applicants(models.Model):
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

I am trying to append a custom variable "selected" to my queryset to track users who appear in both the job_seekers ManytoMany field and the Applicants model using the following code.

```
views.py
        position = get_object_or_404(Position, pk=self.object.pk)
        applicants = Applicant.objects.filter(position=position)
        result_list = position.job_seekers.annotate(selected=F(applicant__user))
```

so I can highlight selected users in my templates with something like

```
 {% if applicant.pk == applicant.selected %}
```

How can I do this without having to change the database structure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try like this using [conditional expression(case)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case):

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, F, Value

applicants = Applicant.objects.filter(position=position).annotate(
    is_selected=Case(
        When(
            user__in = F('position__job_seekers'),
            then=Value(True)
        ),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```

And use it in template:

```
{% for applicant in applicants %}
    {% if applicant.is_selected %}
      // do something
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Worked partially when using position.job_seekers.filter(applicant__position=position ).annotate(  is_selected=Case ... however in template  "applicant in applicants"end up referencing the Position model